# MPAndroidChart how to change the color of the bar chart past the limit line?

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

How to change the color of the bar chart past the limit line?
Now, bars that cross the limit line change color.
But, I want to change the color of the part cross the limit line.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve that with `stackedBarChart`.

Here in the [docs](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/setting-data/) you can see how to add the data for each bar.
With this, you will set the data for a barchart as follows:

`BarEntry(xPosition, floatArray(belowLineNumber, aboverLineNumber)`

For the colors, you just need to add a list of colors fot the data set(two colors in your specific case):

`dataSet.color = listOf(YourColor1, YourColor2)`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer:) All I wanted was to change the color of the chart where it crossed the limit line. I don't think it was delivered properly because of the translator. Thank you.!

Comment: No problem! If You still need some need I can try to help :) thank you for accepting